# Connecting metadata with UIImage from library

Tags: ios, uiimage, metadata, alasset

I am getting images from library as an ALAsset. I get the raw image like this:

```
ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [asset defaultRepresentation];
CGImageRef iref = [rep fullResolutionImage];
UIImage *im = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref];
data4 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(im, 0.5);
```

I can also obtain metadata for it just like this:

```
NSDictionary *data = [rep metadata];
```

which is absolutely fine, but when I want to upload the picture to a server. However when I do that, the picture is uploaded without the metadata. Is there a way how to send it as one-piece?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are asking for ALAsset , send a photo to a web service including its exif data: see [ALAsset , send a photo to a web service including its exif data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6881923/alasset-send-a-photo-to-a-web-service-including-its-exif-data)

Comment: As far as I see there, by that he is caching the files and then sends it to server. What if I want to upload a video that is larger than remaining space on the device? Then I can't cache the file...